# Spring Cloud Gateway - set URI dynamically at startup time

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I wish to use a service discovery call to set my URIs at start up time. For example, I would like to parse this route at start-up time and replace the value of the uri. Ideally a filter should not be the solution, as i dont want to have to check everytime and just want to set the value once, when a "routes" bean is been created.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: my-portal
          uri: https://no.op # will trigger a svc disc lookup. I was hoping i could use the routes id value (my-portal) as the svc disc param 
          predicates:
            - Path=/foo/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/foo(?<segment>.*),/$\{segment}
        - id: my-portal-admin
          uri: https://admin.com # wont trigger a Svc disc lookup
          predicates:
            - Path=/admin/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/foo(?<segment>.*),/$\{segment}
```

I have reviewed https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#the-discoveryclient-route-definition-locator and I dislike it because:

1. it seems all or nothing. Some routes I want to discover the URL for and some I dont. So I would like to control that logic/lookups
2. The index notation is very not nice, and would prefer to define the routes as per above syntax.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be making use of auto-configured `PropertiesRouteDefinitionLocator` bean. Obtain all the `RouteDefinition`s and update necessary ones.

Here is the sample:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthGateway implements CommandLineRunner {

    private PropertiesRouteDefinitionLocator routeDefinitionLocator;

    public AuthGateway(PropertiesRouteDefinitionLocator routeDefinitionLocator) {
        this.routeDefinitionLocator = routeDefinitionLocator;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(AuthGateway.class);
        app.addListeners(new ApplicationPidFileWriter());
        app.run(args);
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        routeDefinitionLocator.getRouteDefinitions()
                .map(this::updateRouteDefinition)
                .subscribe();
    }

    private RouteDefinition updateRouteDefinition(RouteDefinition routeDefinition) {
        if(routeDefinition.getId().equals("my-portal-admin")) {
            URI uri = URI.create("https://admin.com");
            routeDefinition.setUri(uri);
        }
        return routeDefinition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try that out and let u know.